# How to convert HashMap<String, List<String[]>> into a Tree in GWT?

Tags: gwt, checkbox, tree

I got this data which was pulled from Database & I want to convert it into a Tree.

DATA:

```
mom son momText sonText
1   2   Main    Level1
2   4   Level1  Level2
4   5   Level2  Level3
4   7   Level2  Level3
1   8   Main    Level1
8   9   Level1  Level2
```

CODE:

```
List<String[]> testList=new ArrayList<String[]>();;
String[] test1={"1","2","Main","Level1"};
String[] test2={"2","4","Level1","Level2"};
String[] test3={"4","5","Level2","Level3"};
String[] test4={"4","7","Level2","Level3"};
String[] test5={"1","8","Main","Level1"};
String[] test6={"8","9","Level1","Level2"};

testList.add(test1);
testList.add(test2);
testList.add(test3);
testList.add(test4);
testList.add(test5);
testList.add(test6);

HashMap<String, List<String[]>> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, List<String[]>>();
for(int i=0; i<testList.size(); i++){
    String[] test=testList.get(i);
    String parent=test[0];
    List<String[]> children = myHashMap.get(parent);
    if (children == null){
        children = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        myHashMap.put(parent,children);                     
    }
    children.add(test);
}
Tree myTree=new Tree();
String node=testList.get(0)[0];
printTree(node, myTree, myHashMap);
```

I also have a method called "printTree"

```
public void printTree(String node, Tree myTree, HashMap<String, List<String[]>> myHashMap){
    CheckBox nodeCheckBox=new CheckBox(node);
    TreeItem root = new TreeItem(nodeCheckBox);
    myTree.addItem(root);

    if(myHashMap.containsKey(node)){
        List<String[]> testList=myHashMap.get(node);

        for(int i=0; i<testList.size(); i++){
            String nextNode=testList.get(i)[1];
            printTree(nextNode, myTree, myHashMap);
        }

    }
}
```

After running, the output look like this which is not correct:
[image]

I want the result look like this:
[image]

I believe that we need to change a little bit in the printTree function to make it works.

Note 1: if you don't like the way I code, you feel free to provide your own solution, but please use the data in this object `List<String[]> testList`.

Note 2: you don't need to worry about the text (momText & sonText) column, but just try to manipulate the number (mon & son ) column, the text can be easily accessed via string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return tree item that already explain @cyon then Pass display text in method for text:

```
public TreeItem printTree(String node,  HashMap<String, List<String[]>> myHashMap,String displayText){
             CheckBox nodeCheckBox=new CheckBox(displayText);
              TreeItem root = new TreeItem(nodeCheckBox);
              root.setState(true);
              if(myHashMap.containsKey(node)){
                  List<String[]> testList=myHashMap.get(node);

                  for(int i=0; i<testList.size(); i++){
                     String nextNode=testList.get(i)[1];
                     TreeItem child = printTree(nextNode, myHashMap,testList.get(i)[3]);
                     root.addItem(child);
                     root.setState(true);
                  }

               }
               return root;
        }
```

And call your method like

```
Tree myTree=new Tree();
    String node=testList.get(0)[0];
    myTree.addItem(printTree(node, myHashMap,testList.get(0)[2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the `Tree` around you can return the `TreeItem` from the recursive method as follows

```
public TreeItem createTree(String node, HashMap<String, List<String[]>> myHashMap){
  CheckBox nodeCheckBox=new CheckBox(node);
  TreeItem root = new TreeItem(nodeCheckBox);

  if(myHashMap.containsKey(node)){
      List<String[]> testList=myHashMap.get(node);

      for(int i=0; i<testList.size(); i++){
         String nextNode=testList.get(i)[1];
         TreeItem child = createTree(nextNode, myHashMap);
         root.addItem(child);
      }

   }
   return root;
}
```

And then in the main bit of code you just add the root to the tree

```
Tree myTree=new Tree();
String node=testList.get(0)[0];
myTree.addItem(createTree(node, myHashMap));
```

Comment: Hi, great, Thank you very much. There is a very small issue, aft this moment it shows the number, but do u know how to bring the momText & sonText over?

Comment: Like i can loop over the tree widget & just search for the monText & sonText, but do u have any better solution to solve it?

Comment: Well I guess there are multiple ways. The easiest would be to replace all the code that says `testList.get(i)[1]` with `testList.get(i)[3]` and replace everything that says `testList.get(0)[0]` with `testList.get(0)[2]`, and `String parent=test[0];` with `String parent=test[2];` I think.

Comment: You should consider using a class instead of a `String[]` because it will make code more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am planning to do that.